# HTML string to Document object in VBScript

Tags: html, http, vbscript

I have a string containing the HTML of a page as received by a GET request

```
Dim http
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False
http.send
// http.responseText is the string
```

How can I convert this string to a Document object? I would like a more natural way of parsing the HTML than manually searching through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is valid XHTML, then you can load it into a DOMDocument with LoadXml(). Misc example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756007(v=vs.85).aspx

Otherwise, you could use some sort of browser COM object (as previously answered here: [How do you extract data from vendor website in vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067379/how-do-you-extract-data-from-vendor-website-in-vbscript/2068224#2068224)), but NOTE: this is not something you'd want to do server-side in ASP pages, as it's likely to result in all sorts of leaked resources and instability.

Finally, you could use a dedicated HTML-parsing third-party COM object, eg http://www.miken.com/htmlzap/ (I am not recommending this, it's the result of a v quick google search - but it might be great for all I know).